# Can't log into Oracle 19c database running inside a container from the host

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, docker, oracle-19c

I have a server running Oracle 19c inside a Docker container, and I would like the ability to log into the database from the host using `sqlplus`.

Inside the container, I am able to run this command successfully:

`sqlplus john/john@127.0.0.1:1521/XYZ`

However, when ran from outside the container, the command hangs for ~60 seconds then fails and returns this error:

`ORA-12637: Packet receive failed`

**How can I log into the database from the host?**

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.8'
name: db
services:
  database:
    image: doctorkirk/oracle-19c:19.3
    volumes:
      - ~/oracle19c/data/:/opt/oracle/oradata
    ports:
      - 1521:1521
    environment:
      - ORACLE_SID=XYZ
      - ORACLE_PWD=oracle
```

`docker ps`:

```
user@test-db:~$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                        COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                    PORTS                                       NAMES
29ba3a2ebe95   doctorkirk/oracle-19c:19.3   "/bin/sh -c 'exec $O…"   16 minutes ago   Up 15 minutes (healthy)   0.0.0.0:1521->1521/tcp, :::1521->1521/tcp   db-database-1
```

`listener.ora`:

```
LISTENER =
(DESCRIPTION_LIST =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 0.0.0.0)(PORT = 1521))
  )
)

DEDICATED_THROUGH_BROKER_LISTENER=ON
DIAG_ADR_ENABLED = off
```

`netstat -tulpn` from inside the container:

```
[oracle@29ba3a2ebe95 ~]$ netstat -tulpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1521            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      17/tnslsnr
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.11:34963        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:34633           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      88/ora_d000_XYZ
udp        0      0 127.0.0.11:37794        0.0.0.0:*                           -
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:54395         0.0.0.0:*                           90/ora_s000_XYZ
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:38515         0.0.0.0:*                           88/ora_d000_XYZ
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:52421         0.0.0.0:*                           76/ora_lreg_XYZ
```

`netstat -tulpn` from the host:

```
user@test-db:~$ netstat -tulpn
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1521            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::1521                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

Comment: Is the host firewall blocking the connection?

Comment: @pmdba This is minimal Debian install, no firewall by default. Just double-checked `iptables`. Also Docker is binding the port to localhost which most firewalls don't touch. Running `nmap 127.0.0.1 -p 1521 -sV` shows Nmap recognizes the port is running Oracle 19c.

Comment: Additionally, bringing the Docker container down followed by running the same login command immediately (no 60 sec hang) returns a different error: `ORA-12541: TNS:no listener`

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed by pointing SQLPlus to the database container's Docker subnet IP instead of localhost.